# UnityException: Transform child out of bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have six panels were the current effects are showing. If the amount of effects is 0, I want all of them to disappear. The `effectOff()` deactives all panels and effect images. The six panels have each six children effect images. (blue, green, red etc.). The code should make all of them deactivated.

```
public GameObject effectbar;

public void effectOff()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int a = i; i < 6; i++)
        {
            effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).GetChild(a).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    effectbar.SetActive(false);
}
```

The `effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);` line gives a `Transform child out of bounds` exception. How do I fix that? I read that it throws an error because the system doesn't know if a children object really exists. Thanks forwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `effectBar` is the parent of all of your panels, you can write only this line:

```
effectbar.SetActive(false);
```

Because `effectbar` is the parent it will also deactivate the children automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was a spelling mistake (`int a = i; i < 6; i++` should have been `int a = i; a < 6; a++`), but I am still gonna use this line because I really don't have to set all of them false.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is incrementing `i`, so that when the inner loop finishes `i` is `6`, after which the call in your outer loop fires, but your `i` is now out of bounds.

You'll probably want either a different variable incrementing your inner loop, or something else that works depending on what you need.

Comment: Yes, I somehow didn't notice that. But just setting the whole effectbar off works too. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Echi no problem! Deadzone's answer is better than mine - I would accept that.